# How to show image with lines plotted over it on tkinter canvas window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

This program reads an image which is in location C:/Square.png and lines are plotted over it. The plot title is also defined. I want to show this whole image in tkinter window using canvas. How do I do it?

This is the image. The name has to be changed and we can run the code. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEIyQ.jpg

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def plot_output(opt_w, opt_h, n_x, n_y):
    y_start, y_end = 100, 425
    x_start, x_end = 25, 400

    img = plt.imread("C:/Square.png") #Please change the location
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10)) 
    plt.axis('off')
    ax.imshow(img)

    x_interval = (x_end - x_start)/n_x*2

    h_x = range(x_start, x_end, 5)
    for i in range(0,int(n_y)):
        if i != 0:
            ax.plot(h_x, [y_start + (y_end-y_start)/n_y*i]*len(h_x), '--', linewidth=5, color='firebrick')
    plt.title(str(int(n_x*n_y)) + ' ABCD\n'+'TYUI:'+str(opt_w)+', Yummy:'+str(opt_h))

def get_get(min_w, min_h, max_w, max_h, PL, PH, min_t, max_t, cost_m, cost_a):
    x = 1
    if max_w < PL:
        x = math.ceil(PL / max_w)
    cost_rest = cost_m * PL * PH * (max_t + min_t) / 2 + cost_a * PH * x

    cost_y = float("inf")
    y = None
    if min_h == 0:
        min_h = 1
    for i in range(math.ceil(PH / max_h), math.floor(PH / min_h)+1):
        tmp_cost = cost_m * PL * PH * (max_t - min_t) / 2 / i + cost_a * PL * i
        if tmp_cost < cost_y:
            cost_y = tmp_cost
            y = i

    opt_w, opt_h, opt_cost = PL/x, PH/y, cost_rest + cost_y
    plot_output(opt_w, opt_h, x, y)
    return opt_w, opt_h, opt_cost

PL=30
PH=10
min_t=0.1
max_t=0.3
cost_m=0.1
cost_a=0.1
min_w=0.5
min_h=0.5
max_w=4
max_h=3

get_get(min_w, min_h, max_w, max_h, PL, PH, min_t, max_t, cost_m, cost_a)
```

Comment: `canvas.create_image(...)`, `canvas.crete_line(...)`. Doc: [tkinter.Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm)

Comment: @furas where do i use it? i am confused

Comment: you asked for tkinter's Canvas - did you create it ? `canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root)` OR maybe you means matplotlib plot, not tkinter Canvas.

Comment: OR maybe you means [embeding matplotlib plot in tkinter window](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html)

Comment: @furas yes I meant canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root) so that I could move the image wherever I want, how can it be done? really confused coz it has image and the lines on it together in one.

Comment: you would use `imsave()` to write all in file `.png` or `.jpg` and then you can load this file and display it on canvas. Normally you would have to draw every line separatelly on canvas and all ploting with matplotlib is useless for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates image, lines and text (title) on canvas

```
import math
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk

def plot_output(opt_w, opt_h, n_x, n_y):
    global img # solution for PhotoImage bug

    y_start, y_end = 100, 425
    x_start, x_end = 25, 400
    margin_top = 35  # place for title

    # --- image ---

    #img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="image.jpg") #Please change the location
    canvas.create_image(0, margin_top, image=img, anchor='nw')

    canvas['width'] = img.width()
    canvas['height'] = img.height() + margin_top

    # --- lines ---

    y_step = (y_end-y_start)/n_y

    for i in range(1, n_y):
        y = y_start + y_step*i
        y += margin_top  # place for title
        canvas.create_line(x_start, y, x_end, y, fill='red', width=7, dash=(25, 10))

    #for y in range(y_start+y_step, y_end-1, y_step):
    #    y += margin_top  # place for title
    #    canvas.create_line(x_start, y, x_end, y, fill='red', width=7, dash=(25, 10))

    # --- title ---

    text = '{} ABCD\nTYUI:{}, Yummy:{}'.format(int(n_x*n_y), opt_w, opt_h)
    x = img.width()//2 
    y = margin_top  # bottom of title because `create_text` uses `anchor='s'`
    canvas.create_text(x, y, text=text, anchor='s', justify='center')

def get_get(min_w, min_h, max_w, max_h, PL, PH, min_t, max_t, cost_m, cost_a):
    x = 1
    if max_w < PL:
        x = math.ceil(PL / max_w)
    cost_rest = cost_m * PL * PH * (max_t + min_t) / 2 + cost_a * PH * x

    cost_y = float("inf")
    y = None
    if min_h == 0:
        min_h = 1

    for i in range(math.ceil(PH / max_h), math.floor(PH / min_h)+1):
        tmp_cost = cost_m * PL * PH * (max_t - min_t) / 2 / i + cost_a * PL * i
        if tmp_cost < cost_y:
            cost_y = tmp_cost
            y = i

    opt_w, opt_h, opt_cost = PL/x, PH/y, cost_rest + cost_y
    plot_output(opt_w, opt_h, x, y)
    return opt_w, opt_h, opt_cost

# --- main ---

PL = 30
PH = 10
min_t = 0.1
max_t = 0.3
cost_m = 0.1
cost_a = 0.1
min_w = 0.5
min_h = 0.5
max_w = 4
max_h = 3

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=1000, height=1000)
canvas.pack()
get_get(min_w, min_h, max_w, max_h, PL, PH, min_t, max_t, cost_m, cost_a)

root.mainloop()
```